# Jquery .delegate doesn't seem to work for me on hover

Tags: jquery

I have been using jquery's .live for sometime to bind event handlrs to dynamically generated elements.

With the upcoming release of jQuery 1.7 I did some reading on the soon to be deprecated .delegate function and it's replacement in 1.7 .on commands which completely replace .live and should be much faster.

Anyway, I have began to convert some of my .live usage over in my code and while this seems to work fine for 'click' events I cannot get either .delegate or .on to work with any hover/moouseenter events.

Can someone please describe what is wrong with this code and show me what I should be doing?

```
$('body').delegate('.project_open', 'mouseenter', function() {

    $(this).addClass("hovered");

  });
```

Now The container for .project_open is dynamically generated which is why I am using 'body' as the handler which does not change.  This is exactly the same if I use the new .on function.

If I use .live it works perfectly.  Any ideas where I am going wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If .project_open is inside another control like ul or div or something another it will not work.

it will work in this case:

```
<body>
  <div class=".project_open">
  </div>
</body>
$('body').delegate('.project_open', 'mouseenter', function() {

    $(this).addClass("hovered");

  });
```

It will NOT work in this case, so if you append additional container.

```
<body>
  <div>
      <div class=".project_open">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
$('body').delegate('.project_open', 'mouseenter', function() {

    $(this).addClass("hovered");

  });
```

Comment: I see, so would .live still be recommended in this case?  Or can still use .delegate by being more specific with my selectors?

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'on' on the class selector:

```
$('.project_open').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
});
```

Theory delegate:

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root
>   elements. As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the
>   .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most
>   effective means to use event delegation. More information on event
>   binding and delegation is in the .on() method.

Theory live:

> Description: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and in the future. As of jQuery 1.7, the .live()
>   method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of
>   older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to
>   .live(). This method provides a means to attach delegated event
>   handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use
>   of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page. See the
>   discussion of direct versus delegated events in the .on() method for
>   more information. Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its
>   successors is straightforward.

Check for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/hgGec

Comment: Thanks, but for some strange reason this doesn't work for me.  Using the exact same code as your example throws me a jQuery error = (a || "").split is not a function.  If I replace 'delegate' with 'live', everything works fine. Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to work either.